# Fixing PDO Exception on Bake

Tags: cakephp, pdo, cakephp-3.0

I've just created a new project and I'm trying to bake my tables. I've added the database config information to the config/app file and MySQL is running. When I run bake i get the following error:

> Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in
>   [/Users/Marcus/PhPStormProjects/comet_mobile/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php, line 48]

Can anyone tell me what this is referring to or how to fix it?

Comment: What version of CakePHP?

Comment: Have you run `composer update`? The error message seems relatively straightforward, you're missing a file.

Comment: I ran composer update and got Composer could not find a composer.json file in /Users/Marcus. Then I did the same in my project directory and got: Cannot create cache directory /Users/Marcus/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /Users/Marcus/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache.  it seemed to update successfully but when I attemped to bake again and it failed with the same error.

Comment: Did the composer update again with sudo which got rid of the second error, but I'm still getting the pdo exception.

Comment: Exceptions usually come with a detailed stracktrace. Also please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (`vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.TXT`).

Comment: Also have you tried any of the [possible solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQLSTATE%5BHY000%5D+%5B2002%5D+No+such+file+or+directory) that can be found by searching for the error message?

Comment: welp, changing the host to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost fixed it o.0